# How can I split a list into multiple other lists?

Tags: scala, list

I only recently started working with Scala and I came face to face with a problem I can't seem to find a solution to. So basically, I'm given an input text file by the name of "in.txt", which includes lines of coordinates that I have to work with like I've shown bellow.

```
2 1
6 6
4 2
2 5
2 6
2 7
3 4
6 1
6 2
2 3
6 3
6 4
6 5
6 7
```

I decided to use a List to store all the values so I could use built in functions to do calculations with the values afterwards.

```
val lines = io.Source.fromFile("in.txt").getLines

val coordinates =
  lines
    .drop(0)
    .toList
    .sortWith(_<_)
    .mkString
    .replaceAll("\\s", "")
    .grouped(2)
    .toList
```

Everything works as it should, as the output of *println(coordinates)* is

```
List(21, 23, 25, 26, 27, 34, 42, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67)
```

But what I want to do next is to create multiple lists out of this one. For example, a new list should be created if, for example, a value starts with "2", and all the values that start with "2" would be placed in the new list like this:

```
List(21, 23, 25, 26, 27)
```

Then the same would be done with "3", then "4" and so on.

Using functions such as *.partition* and *.groupBy* works, but taking into account the fact that the values in the coordinates can also reach 4 digit numbers, and that they can change if the input file is edited, it would be a pain to write all those conditions manually. So basically my question is this: Is it possible to achieve this by making use of Scala's functionality, some sort of form of iterations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your file can take a mixture of 2, 3, 4, ... digit strings.

```
scala> val l = List("12", "13", "123", "1234")
l: List[String] = List(12, 13, 123, 1234)

scala> val grouped = l.groupBy(s => s.take(s.length - 1)).values
grouped: Iterable[List[String]] = MapLike(List(123), List(12, 13), List(1234))
```

If you want this sorted:

```
val grouped = l.groupBy(s => s.take(s.length - 1)).toSeq.sortBy(_._1).map{ case (_, l) => l.sorted}

grouped: Seq[List[String]] = ArrayBuffer(List(12, 13), List(123), List(1234))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all your input conditions with a range:

```
val conditions = 1 to 9999
```

And then foldLeft them filtering your original list by each of its elements:

```
conditions.foldLeft(List():List[List[Int]])((acc, elem) => l.filter(_.toString.startsWith(elem.toString))::acc).filterNot(_.isEmpty)
```

**Output**

```
res28: List[List[Int]] = List(List(67), List(66), List(65), List(64), List(63), List(62), List(61), List(42), List(34), List(27), List(26), List(25), List(23), List(21), List(61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67), List(42), List(34), List(21, 23, 25, 26, 27))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also does the job perfectly!